# Use google analytics to capture touch events in a slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, google-analytics

So I been trying to track mobile swipes where inside the slider there is other swipes.  Look the image below.  The code you see attached is part of my Google Analytics events tracking code.

[image: this is how my UI looks like (mockup)]

Here is my code:

```
          // Shop buttons
          jQuery('.shop-btn-group a').click(function(event) {
              var clickedLink = jQuery(this);
              var gaqArgs = ['_trackEvent', 'Shop'];
              var validShopLink = false;

              if ( clickedLink.hasClass('shop-women') ) {
                  validShopLink = true;
                  gaqArgs.push('Click-Shop');
              }

              if (this.rel) {
                  gaqArgs.push(this.rel);
              }

              if (validShopLink) {

                  // Check if the user is using a keyboard command to open the link in a new tab
                  if (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey) {
                      try {
                        _gaq.push(gaqArgs);
                      }
                      catch(err) {}
                      return;
                  }
                  else {
                      event.preventDefault();

                      try {
                        _gaq.push(gaqArgs);
                        _gaq.push(function() {
                            document.location = clickedLink[0].href;
                        });
                      }
                      catch(err) {
                          document.location = this.href;
                      }
                  }
              }
          });

          // Product click
          jQuery('.image-wrap a').click(function(event) {
              var clickedLink = jQuery(this);
              var gaqArgs = ['_trackEvent', 'Shop'];
              var validShopLink = false;

              if ( clickedLink.hasClass('frame-image') ) {
                  validShopLink = true;
                  gaqArgs.push('Click-Product');
              }

              if (this.rel) {
                  gaqArgs.push(this.rel);
              }

              if (validShopLink) {

                  // Check if the user is using a keyboard command to open the link in a new tab
                  if (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey) {
                      try {
                        _gaq.push(gaqArgs);
                      }
                      catch(err) {}
                      return;
                  }
                  else {
                      event.preventDefault();

                      try {
                        _gaq.push(gaqArgs);
                        _gaq.push(function() {
                            document.location = clickedLink[0].href;
                        });
                      }
                      catch(err) {
                          document.location = this.href;
                      }
                  }
              }
          });

          // Color dots
          jQuery('.color-dots .dot').click(function(event) {
              var dot = jQuery(this);
              var colorIndex = dot.index();
              var sku = null;
              try {
                  var link = dot.closest('.color-dots')
                      .siblings('.btn-wrapper')
                      .eq(0)
                      .find('.shop-btn-group')
                      .eq(colorIndex)
                      .children('a')
                      .eq(0);
                  if ( link[0].rel ) {
                      sku = link[0].rel;
                  }
              }
              catch(err) {}

              if (sku) {
                  try {
                     _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Shop', 'Click-Color', sku]);
                  }
                  catch(err) {}
              }
          });
```

Any help will be awesome thanks in advance.

Comment: What issues are you having? Is it simply not registering the GA event?

Comment: Yeap the swiping event is not triggering

Comment: I see nothing in your code except `click` events. Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24149485/901048) help?