# Track swipes with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, swipe, gesture

I have a swipe functionality on my mobile page, and I want to used touchstart, touchend, and touchmove to track the swipe functionality across the device without affecting the scrolling.

Here is my code.

```
jQuery('.first-frame').bind('touchmove', function(event) {
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Landing-Page', 'Swipe-Toggle-Color', '0259_2190']);
});
```

Comment: What goes wrong with your code?

Comment: It triggers the event when scrolling instead of swipe only and it get timeout

Comment: Are you using jQuery Mobile, or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

If it's possible to only monitor the [`swipeleft`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipeleft/) and [`swiperight`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swiperight/) events in jQuery Mobile instead, do so.

Otherwise, you can set a global variable on the `scroll` event that resets after, say, 0.2 seconds. Then have the `touchmove` event check if that variable is set, and if it is, don't trigger Google Analytics.

```
window.is_scrolling = false; // global variable
window.timeout_id = 0;

window.onscroll = function() {
    window.is_scrolling = true;
    clearTimeout(window.timeout_id);
    window.timeout_id = setTimeout(function() { 
        window.is_scrolling = false; 
    }, 200); // milliseconds
};

jQuery('.first-frame').bind('touchmove', function(event) {
    if (!window.is_scrolling) 
       _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Landing-Page', 'Swipe-Toggle-Color', '0259_2190']);
});
```

Comment: Only jQuery cant use jQuery Mobile

Comment: Ok -- will leave the comment in my answer anyway, for future visitors.

Comment: does it make sense to have a if else with the google analytics push

Comment: Probably not. The "else" just means you're scrolling instead of swiping.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a touchmove, touchend, and touchstart example but I would use a combination of HammerJS (https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/) and custom Google events to take the guess work out of it.

```
var element = $(".first-frame")[0];

var trackswipe = Hammer(element, {
  drag: false,
  transform: false,
  swipe: true,
  swipeVelocityX: 0 // Adjust to liking...
}).on("swipe", function(event) {
  if (event.gesture.direction === "left") {
    // Track Something
    return false;
  } else if (event.gesture.direction === "right") {
    // Track something else.
    return false;
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: can't used any library except for jQuery